# Data sent by WCF client is broken

Tags: wcf

We are getting following exception in the `.svclog` file generated through system diagnostics config settings at server side.

> Exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException
>   Message: The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length
>   header.  There may have been a network error or the client may be
>   sending invalid requests.

We have observed that the data sent by WCF client is broken. We came to know about this by viewing the message xml in the `.svclog` file generated at WCF client side.

Actually we are sending data large data by dividing it into small chunks calling the WCF service method to send data in a loop. Following is the code for the same at WCF client side.

```
DataTable dtStockDetails = new DataTable("StockDetails");
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtStockDetails);

int stockDetailsBatchSize = 100;
DataTable dtStockDetailsBatch = dtStockDetails.Clone();
DataRow dr;
int stockDetailsBatchCount = 0;
int stockDetailsTotalRecords = dtStockDetails.Rows.Count;

while (dtStockDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dr = dtStockDetails.Rows[0];

    dtStockDetailsBatch.ImportRow(dr);
    dtStockDetailsBatch.AcceptChanges();

    dtStockDetails.Rows.Remove(dr);
    dtStockDetails.AcceptChanges();

    if ((dtStockDetailsBatch.Rows.Count == stockDetailsBatchSize) || (dtStockDetails.Rows.Count == 0))
    {
        stockDetailsBatchCount++;
        sendStockDetailsResult = serviceClient.SendStockDetails(dtStockDetailsBatch);
        dtStockDetailsBatch.Clear();
    }
}
```

Now WCF client some times sends 7 batches of data, some times sends 9 batches of data, some times sends 10 batches of data, .... . In all cases lase message(data batch) xml gets corrupted. This behavior is random.

We are not sure why the message xml is getting corrupted and resulting into end of communication. It never sends all batches of data.

Following are config settings:

### WCF Service config settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="InventoryServices.InventoryImportServiceBehavior"
      name="InventoryServices.InventoryImportService">
      <endpoint address="https://www.domain.com/InventoryServices/InventoryImportService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="wsServiceEndpointBehavior"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="b1" contract="InventoryServices.IInventoryImportService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="https://www.domain.com" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="b1" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:30:00" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate">
          </transport>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="wsServiceEndpointBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="InventoryServices.InventoryImportServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="XyzClient" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="InventoryServices.Helpers.CustomValidator, InventoryServices" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

### WCF Client config settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647" />
  </diagnostics>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IInventoryImportService"
          closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
          sendTimeout="00:30:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"
            enabled="false" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="">
            <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
          </transport>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://www.domain.com/InventoryServices/InventoryImportService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IInventoryImportService"
            contract="InventoryImportService.IInventoryImportService"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IInventoryImportService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"
      propagateActivity="false">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="sharedListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="sharedListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="C:\Program Files\InventoryExportUtilitySetup\servicetrace.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="sharedListener">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Can any one please suggest what should we do to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your configuration the Reader Quotas settings on Server and Client are different. 
Make sure you have large values mostly same on client and server.

Just wanted to know if you have tried sending in any small payload data to make sure that the service is working fine?

I also noticed that you have your security set to "TransportWithMessageCredential" and you have the mex endpoint with mexHttpBinding. I guess that should have been mexHttpsBinding and also your httpGetEnabled attribute is set to true where as it should have been httpsGetEnabled to true.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We tried with your suggestions but still the problem is there with the same behavior. We have tried with changing **stockDetailsBatchSize** but after transferring 4500 to 5000 records the communication gets stopped regardless of **stockDetailsBatchSize**.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the request using Fiddler or wireshark. Also make sure to set the httpruntime maxrequestlength attribute to a large value